# Add Singularity to every snakemake rule that uses conda

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I created a snakemake pipline that heavily depends on conda.
I have users that don't have access to conda. They ask if there is a container version of the pipeline. Obvioulsy, it's possible to put the whole pipeline in a container but then it cannot access different servers on cloud/cluster system.

I added `container: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.4.10"` which would use this for all rules.

Some only use python so there is a overhead for those rules.

Is there a way to use singularity only for those rules that use conda.

I tried:

```
for r in workflow.rules:

    if r.conda_env is not None:

        r.container_img=  "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.4.10"
```

This works, but there is still the `r.is_containerized` which is false. should I activate this.